# I want to set a border or stroke for a image ,Is it possible in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This is my code:

```
local leftRect = display.newImageRect( "rect.png",90, 30 )
leftRect.x =155
leftRect.y = 150
BgGroup:insert(leftRect)
```

Here, I need the left border or a stroke line.
I don't know it is possible please answer me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar ) 

local rect = display.newRect(135, 100, 50, 50)
rect:setFillColor(255, 255, 255) 
rect:setStrokeColor(140, 140, 140) 
rect.strokeWidth = 5
```

I don't know if it works for imagerects, it should.
If not you could always place your image Within such a rect

Answer (score 0):

```
leftRect.strokeWidth = 5
```

It works for me